# I Do Recieve Errors During Migrate

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.10

I just add new apps to my setting.py and i wont to migrate and apply them but is giving me errors. please GUYS help me out
i make sure there are not errors in any of my code so have try all i could but still cant solve this  problem.

THIS ARE THE APPS I WONT TO MIGRATE

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profiles',
    'contact',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]
```

THIS IS THE ERROR IS GIVING ME IN MY TERMINAL

```
(classicplanet) C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\src>python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, profiles, sessions,
sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  Applying account.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\db\migratio
ns\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_i
nitial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\db\migratio
ns\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_
initial)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\db\migratio
ns\executor.py", line 247, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\sqlite3\schema.py", line 34, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\classicplanet\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\sqlite3\base.py", line 318, in check_constraints
    bad_value, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'django_admin_log' with primary
 key '1' has an invalid foreign key: django_admin_log.user_id contains a value '
1' that does not have a corresponding value in auth_user__old.id.
```

Comment: Did you manually delete some records, specifically an `User` with id 1?

Comment: no i dont do that